# How to avoid automatic changing of data type in panda dataframe and convert into CSV in python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to convert Json file to csv using pandas in python

json file data:

```
[{
    "source": "https://www.na-kd.com/en/sweaters/cardigans/button-up-ribbed-cropped-cardigan-pink",
    "class_ids": "3_33",
    "id_matrix": "0_0_0_1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0",
    "tags": "cardigan_neckline",
    "front": "https://www.na-kd.com/globalassets/nakd_button_up_ribbed_cropped_cardigan_1018-004495-0211_01g.jpg",
    "back": "https://www.na-kd.com/globalassets/nakd_button_up_ribbed_cropped_cardigan_1018-004495-0211_02a.jpg",
    "left": "https://www.na-kd.com/globalassets/nakd_button_up_ribbed_cropped_cardigan_1018-004495-0211_03b.jpg",
    "right": "https://www.na-kd.com/globalassets/nakd_button_up_ribbed_cropped_cardigan_1018-004495-0211_04c.jpg",
    "zoomedin": "https://www.na-kd.com/globalassets/nakd_button_up_ribbed_cropped_cardigan_1018-004495-0211_05g.jpg",
    "otherurl": "https://www.na-kd.com/globalassets/nakd_button_up_ribbed_cropped_cardigan_1018-004495-0211_05g.jpg"
}, {...}, {...}]
```

My code to convert into CSV file..(but pandas automatically change datatype of "id_matrix" and "class_ids" and i want to these column string..

```
raw_data=pd.read_json('/home/mobin/PycharmProjects/na-kd/Jsons/mapped_improvedcheck.json')
raw_data.to_csv("csv_file/samplecheck.csv")

result = raw_data.dtypes
print(result)
print(raw_data['id_matrix'][:10])
```

output of this code:

```
source        object
class_ids      int64
id_matrix    float64
tags          object
front         object
back          object
left          object
right         object
zoomedin      object
otherurl      object
dtype: object
0    1.000000e+43
1    1.000000e+43
2    1.000000e+43
3    1.000000e+43
4    1.000000e+43
5    1.000000e+43
6    1.000000e+43
7    1.000000e+43
8    1.000000e+43
9    1.000000e+43
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) attribute of `pandas.DataFrame` :

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = pd.read_json('/home/mobin/PycharmProjects/na-kd/Jsons/mapped_improvedcheck.json')
raw_data2 = raw_data.astype('object')
raw_data2.to_csv('csv_file/samplecheck.csv')

result = raw_data2.dtypes
print(result)
print(raw_data2['id_matrix'][:10])
```

**Update :** what I get inside the `samplecheck.csv` file is :

```
,back,class_ids,front,id_matrix,left,otherurl,right,source,tags,zoomedin
0,https://www.na-kd.com/globalassets/nakd_button_up_ribbed_cropped_cardigan_1018-004495-0211_02a.jpg,333,https://www.na-kd.com/globalassets/nakd_button_up_ribbed_cropped_cardigan_1018-004495-0211_01g.jpg,1e+42,https://www.na-kd.com/globalassets/nakd_button_up_ribbed_cropped_cardigan_1018-004495-0211_03b.jpg,https://www.na-kd.com/globalassets/nakd_button_up_ribbed_cropped_cardigan_1018-004495-0211_05g.jpg,https://www.na-kd.com/globalassets/nakd_button_up_ribbed_cropped_cardigan_1018-004495-0211_04c.jpg,https://www.na-kd.com/en/sweaters/cardigans/button-up-ribbed-cropped-cardigan-pink,cardigan_neckline,https://www.na-kd.com/globalassets/nakd_button_up_ribbed_cropped_cardigan_1018-004495-0211_05g.jpg
```

Comment: this code convert float to object but not giving me my require output ,while writing in csv the same problem occure..
Your code output:

`source       object
class_ids    object
id_matrix    object
tags         object
front        object
back         object
left         object
right        object
zoomedin     object
otherurl     object
dtype: object
0    1e+43
1    1e+43
2    1e+43
3    1e+43
4    1e+43
5    1e+43
6    1e+43
7    1e+43
8    1e+43
9    1e+43
Name: id_matrix, dtype: object`